# Why is backslash in script being removed when used with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this C# code, which generates 1 startup script for each file found in a certain directory:

```
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo item in _imageAddress.GetFiles())
{
    db.insertXmlNode("SliderInformation", "SliderImageAddress", "..\\Uploades\\Img\\" + item.Name + ",", "Name", counter++.ToString());
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", @"loadNewPic('..\Uploades\Img\'" + item.Name + ",');", true);
}
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
function loadNewPic(picName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Static/Css/xml/data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            console.log("NAME:   " + picName)
            $(xml).find('SliderInformation').each(function () {
                _name = $(this).find('SliderImageAddress:contains(' + picName + ')').text();
                console.log(_name);
            });

            var k = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < listToAray(_name, ",").length; i++) {
                setTimeout(function () { 
                    $("#image-holder")
                        .append("<img src='" + listToAray(_name, ",")[k] + "' width='80' height='80' />")
                        .fadeIn('slow'); k++; 
                }, 300 * i);
            }
        }
    });
}

function listToAray(fullString, separator) {
    var fullArray = [];
    if (fullString !== undefined) {
        if (fullString.indexOf(separator) == -1) {
            fullAray.push(fullString);
        } else {
            fullArray = fullString.split(separator);
            fullArray.pop(-1)
        }
    }

    return fullArray;
}
```

Even though I'm generating my script calls to `loadNewPic` *with* backslashes, **I'm getting values *without* backslashes** when I output `picName` to the browsers console.

I'm getting this:
`..UploadesImg'Hydrangeas.jpg`

But i want retrieve this:
`..\Uploades\Img\Hydrangeas.jpg`

why backslash is removed?

Comment: @TweeZz, please remove your close vote... your linked post has no accepted answer.

Comment: mmm ok.. even if it contains the correct answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are composing a script (server side) which contains a string, you need to encode that string using [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)

Please try something like:

```
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo item in _imageAddress.GetFiles())
{
    ...
    var pathToImageEncoded = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("..\Uploades\Img\" + item.Name);
    var scriptToLoadPic = string.Format("loadNewPic('{0}');", pathToImageEncoded);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", scriptToLoadPic, true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because it's iterpolating the string.  `\` is a control character and you will need to escape it with a backslash `\\`.

(side note: your question has far too much complexity for what you are asking - keep cutting it down and cutting it down until you get the smallest piece that demonstrates the problem.  -- this might help you figure it out too.)

edit: see comment below - it's unclear where you are seeing problems, you values are also being used in munged strings in the javascript, it's possible it's the javascript that's doing the interpolation.

Comment: Defining a string in C# using `@` does *not* require you to escape a `\\` afaik.

Comment: @DrLivingston, ichanged this to \\ but get same result.

Comment: @user3237074, yes, that's exactly what I meant. There should be no need to escape special characters when you use `@`. But when you don't use `@`, you *must* escape `\\`.

Comment: @TweeZz ok 
now my code with out @ is
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "loadNewPic('..\\Uploades\\Img\\'" + item.Name + ",');", true);
and if i changed to this i get error
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "loadNewPic('..\Uploades\Img\'" + item.Name + ",');", true);

Comment: I did not say that removing the `\\` might somehow fix your issue :)
Please try what I wrote in my answer..

Comment: @TweeZz sorry,I do not understand what you mean.can you show me code?please

Comment: I haven't been on windows in a while - doesn't everything support forward slashes now these days anyway? just use those ;-)

Comment: There's also layers of obfuscation in the example, when you say "I get X..." where do you get that?  You are taking those values and munging them in the javascript too - it's possible it's the javascript that doing the interpolation here not the C#.  Again, you should simplify this and then make a jsfiddle.